# AS3 WebSocket library dont update the readyState for send messages

Tags: node.js, actionscript-3, flash, websocket

I have an AS3 Websocket client who can connect to node-js  server, successfully.

On the client, the WebSocket class have this atributes:

```js
  private static const CONNECTING:int = 0;
  private static const OPEN:int = 1;
  private static const CLOSING:int = 2;
  private static const CLOSED:int = 3;

  private var readyState:int = CONNECTING;
```

When I make a connection with the server, the client trigger the function "onSocketData()" (this function is in WebSocket class) and  must to change the value of the parameter "readyState" to "1", with this value the client can send messages to the server.

Problem:

The process of the function "onSocketData()" never change the value of "readyState".

Here is the code of the onSocketData() function :

```js
 private function onSocketData(event:ProgressEvent):void {
   trace(readyState);
    var pos:int = buffer.length;
    socket.readBytes(buffer, pos);
 
    for (; pos < buffer.length; ++pos) {
  trace(buffer.length + "   pos-->" + pos + "  headerState -->" + headerState+"  buferpos -->"+buffer[pos]);
  
      if (headerState < 4) {
        // try to find "\r\n\r\n"
  
        if ((headerState == 0 || headerState == 2) && buffer[pos] == 0x0d) {//this sentence is never fulfilled
          ++headerState;
        } else if ((headerState == 1 || headerState == 3) && buffer[pos] == 0x0a) {//this sentence is never fulfilled
          ++headerState;
    
        } else {
   
          headerState = 0;
        }
        if (headerState == 4) {
   
          var headerStr:String = readUTFBytes(buffer, 0, pos + 1);
          trace("response header:\n" + headerStr);
          if (!validateHandshake(headerStr)) return;
          removeBufferBefore(pos + 1);
          pos = -1;
          readyState = OPEN;// here must be changue the value
          this.dispatchEvent(new WebSocketEvent("open"));
        }
      } else {
   
        var frame:WebSocketFrame = parseFrame();
        if (frame) {
    
    removeBufferBefore(frame.length);
          pos = -1;
          if (frame.rsv != 0) {
            close(1002, "RSV must be 0.");
          } else if (frame.mask) {
            close(1002, "Frame from server must not be masked.");
          } else if (frame.opcode >= 0x08 && frame.opcode <= 0x0f && frame.payload.length >= 126) {
            close(1004, "Payload of control frame must be less than 126 bytes.");
          } else {
            switch (frame.opcode) {
              case OPCODE_CONTINUATION:
                if (fragmentsBuffer == null) {
                  close(1002, "Unexpected continuation frame");
                } else {
                  fragmentsBuffer.writeBytes(frame.payload);
                  if (frame.fin) {
                    data = readUTFBytes(fragmentsBuffer, 0, fragmentsBuffer.length);
                    try {
                      this.dispatchEvent(new WebSocketEvent("message", encodeURIComponent(data)));
                    } catch (ex:URIError) {
                      close(1007, "URIError while encoding the received data.");
                    }
                    fragmentsBuffer = null;
                  }
                }
                break;
              case OPCODE_TEXT:
                if (frame.fin) {
                var data:String = readUTFBytes(frame.payload, 0, frame.payload.length);
                try {
                  this.dispatchEvent(new WebSocketEvent("message", encodeURIComponent(data)));
                } catch (ex:URIError) {
                  close(1007, "URIError while encoding the received data.");
                }
                } else {
                  fragmentsBuffer = new ByteArray();
                  fragmentsBuffer.writeBytes(frame.payload);
                }
                break;
              case OPCODE_BINARY:
                // See https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js/pull/89
                // for discussion about supporting binary data.
                close(1003, "Received binary data, which is not supported.");
                break;
              case OPCODE_CLOSE:
                // Extracts code and reason string.
                var code:int = STATUS_NO_CODE;
                var reason:String = "";
                if (frame.payload.length >= 2) {
                  frame.payload.endian = Endian.BIG_ENDIAN;
                  frame.payload.position = 0;
                  code = frame.payload.readUnsignedShort();
                  reason = readUTFBytes(frame.payload, 2, frame.payload.length - 2);
                }
                trace("received closing frame");
                close(code, reason, "server");
                break;
              case OPCODE_PING:
                sendPong(frame.payload);
                break;
              case OPCODE_PONG:
                break;
              default:
                close(1002, "Received unknown opcode: " + frame.opcode);
                break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

the sentences :

"if ((headerState == 0 || headerState == 2) && buffer[pos] == 0x0d) "

and

"if ((headerState == 1 || headerState == 3) && buffer[pos] == 0x0a)"

are never  fulfilled, so the parameter "headerState" never will add +1, then the sentence

" if (headerState == 4)"

never will fulfilled, and readyState never will take the "1"  (1 means Open conection)

can you help me to fix this?, if I am wrong in my explanation, can you tell me what I have to do to make this code work?

Note: when I force the changue of readyState  to 1, the messages are released and the server can read it, but when I send like a 4 or more messages the server give me an overflow error.

Comment: resolved :), the error was de header sent from server.